# Contar cuantas veces se repite un digito

Tags: c++, switch

```
cout<<"Introduzca el               numero":cin>>N:
while(N>0)
{d=N%10;
Switch(d)
{case l: cl=c1+l; break;
case 2: c2=c2+1: break:
case 3: c3=c3+1: break;
case 4: c4=c4+1; break;
case 5: c5=c5+1; break;
case 6: C6=c6+1; break;
case 7: c7=c7+1; break;
case 8: c8=c8+1; break;
case 9: c9=c9+1; break;
default:cout<<"ERROR";
}
N=N/10;
}
Cout<<0<<"se repite"<<c0<<endl;
Cout<<1<<"se repite"<<c1<<endl;
Cout<<2<<"se repite"<<c2<<endl;
Cout<<3<<"se repite"<<c3<<end];
Cout<<4«<"se repite"<<c4<<endl;
Cout<<5<<"se repite"<<c5<<endl;
Cout<<6<<"se repite"<<c6<<endl;
Cout<<7<<"se repite"<<c7<<endl;
Cout<<8<<"se repite"<<c8<<endl;
Cout<<9<<"se repite"<<c9<<endl;
```

El programa funciona bien, pero       por ejemplo si pongo 20223 solo         quiero que me muestre cuantas veces      se repite el 0 el 2 y el 3 no quiero   que muestre todos los dígitos como lo hace mi programa.

Comment: Y tu `int main()`?, además, hay muchas variables que no están definidas. También, al final de cada lineal de código es con `;` y no con `:`... Si dices que el código te funciona bien, muéstranos el código completo, porque no creo que te funcione con el código que muestras...

Comment: También no es `Switch`, es `switch`, tampoco `Cout`, es `cout`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev toca suponer que en su código sí tiene la función `main` y solo copió un fragmento.

Comment: No quedaba de otra... pero es bueno hacérselo saber al OP... :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Las siguientes observaciones son los errores de sintaxis que encontré en tu código:

- Tal cual como te mencionaba en los comentarios, faltaría tu `int main()` para que inicialices el programa.
- Encontré muchas variables que faltaban ser inicializadas en `0`.
- No existe `Switch`, debería ser `switch`, también el `Cout`, debería ser `cout`.
- Algunas líneas de código terminaban en `:`, debería ser `;`

##### Ahora vamos con la solución a tu problema:

Una vez arreglando las observaciones que te mencioné, logré compilar tu código y en el **output** me muestran los números que se repiten y los que no se repiten, y justamente lo que necesitas es que no muestren los números cuyo no se repiten (se repite 0 veces):

```
// Introduzca el numero: 222233445

// El numero 1 se repite 0 veces // <- no debería mostrar
// El numero 2 se repite 4 veces
// El numero 3 se repite 2 veces
// El numero 4 se repite 2 veces
// El numero 5 se repite 1 veces
// El numero 6 se repite 0 veces // <- no debería mostrar
// El numero 7 se repite 0 veces // <- no debería mostrar
// El numero 8 se repite 0 veces // <- no debería mostrar
// El numero 9 se repite 0 veces // <- no debería mostrar
// El numero 0 se repite 0 veces // <- no debería mostrar
```

La solución a esto sería simplemente validar de que si el contador de veces repetidos es distinto `0`, muestre el mensaje, de lo contrario (si es 0), no lo mostrará:

```
if (c1 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 1 << " se repite " << c1 << " veces" << endl;
if (c2 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 2 << " se repite " << c2 << " veces" << endl;
if (c3 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 3 << " se repite " << c3 << " veces" << endl;
if (c4 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 4 << " se repite " << c4 << " veces" << endl;
if (c5 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 5 << " se repite " << c5 << " veces" << endl;
if (c6 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 6 << " se repite " << c6 << " veces" << endl;
if (c7 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 7 << " se repite " << c7 << " veces" << endl;
if (c8 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 8 << " se repite " << c8 << " veces" << endl;
if (c9 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 9 << " se repite " << c9 << " veces" << endl;
if (c0 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 0 << " se repite " << c0 << " veces" << endl;
```

Tu código final sería el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numero = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c4 = 0, c5 = 0, c6 = 0, c7 = 0, c8 = 0, c9 = 0, c0 = 0;

    cout << "Introduzca el numero: ";
    cin >> numero;
    
    cout << endl;

    while (numero > 0)
    {
        d = numero % 10;

        switch (d)
        {
        case 1:
            c1 = c1 + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            c2 = c2 + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            c3 = c3 + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            c4 = c4 + 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            c5 = c5 + 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            c6 = c6 + 1;
            break;
        case 7:
            c7 = c7 + 1;
            break;
        case 8:
            c8 = c8 + 1;
            break;
        case 9:
            c9 = c9 + 1;
            break;
        case 0:
            c0 = c0 + 1;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Ocurrio un error.";
        }
        numero = numero / 10;
    }

    if (c1 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 1 << " se repite " << c1 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c2 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 2 << " se repite " << c2 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c3 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 3 << " se repite " << c3 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c4 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 4 << " se repite " << c4 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c5 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 5 << " se repite " << c5 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c6 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 6 << " se repite " << c6 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c7 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 7 << " se repite " << c7 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c8 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 8 << " se repite " << c8 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c9 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 9 << " se repite " << c9 << " veces" << endl;
    if (c0 != 0) cout << "El numero " << 0 << " se repite " << c0 << " veces" << endl;
    
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Introduzca el numero: 222233445

// El numero 2 se repite 4 veces
// El numero 3 se repite 2 veces
// El numero 4 se repite 2 veces
// El numero 5 se repite 1 veces

// Introduzca el numero: 20223

// El numero 2 se repite 3 veces
// El numero 3 se repite 1 veces
// El numero 0 se repite 1 veces
```

Comment: Gracias y perdón por no poner completo el código solo agarre una parte

Comment: Ok estimado, recuerda que si te sirvió la respuesta, la puedes marcar como resuelta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En la primera línea de tu código estás usando `:`. Pero tienes que usar `;` para indicar el final de la instrucción. De lo contrario obtendrás errores de compilación.

---

Podrías introducir una variable `minVeces` y mostrar cada variable que haya contado al menos `minVeces`.

```
int minVeces = 1

...

if (c0 >= minVeces)
    cout<<0<<"se repite"<<c0<<endl;
if (c1 >= minVeces)
    cout<<1<<"se repite"<<c1<<endl;
...
```

Pero el código se vuelve aún más tedioso de escribir y analizar.

Así que mejor reemplaza la variable de cada dígito por un arreglo de 10 elementos, uno para cada dígito.

De esta forma puedes generalizar el código usando el dígito cómo posición del arreglo y ciclos para realizar la misma tarea para cada uno de sus elementos.

Además puedes conviertir el procedimiento de contar los dígitos en una función para poder reutilizarlo y obtienes un código así:

```
#include <iostream>

void contarDigitos(int n, int veces[]){
    // Restablece las veces.
    // Puedes omitirlo. Solo que le estarías dejando la responsabilidad
    // a quien llame la función de reestablecer los elementos a 0.
    // En caso de que no lo haga, las cuentas se acumularán.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        veces[i] = 0;
    
    // Cuenta cada dígito
    while (n > 0){
        int digito = n % 10;
        veces[digito]++;
        n /= 10;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n = 0, minVeces = 1;
    int veces[10];

    std::cin >> n;
    contarDigitos(n, veces);

    for (int digito = 0; digito < 10; digito++)
        if (veces[digito] >= minVeces)
            std::cout << digito << " se repite " << veces[digito] << " veces.\n";
    
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##XVFNb4MwDL3nV1idJlGxDSi38nHaL9hhl40DC2lriSaIpN1h4rezxEFhzAecPD@/2A8@DM9nzuf5ASXvb52AEpU2o2ivNWN3hR1wJU07vuIZjdIRSgPyCVy6Cy70R7P/YWAjSeBNaNN@9RaGvtW@TrWTGoE6ESpIC5tKyFyO4z0RXHg5bIhCKH2@L9gLiCTUkC5PuXBqHc1k@RIend4/KV9u4ngtSEiqwJzYxJjTubYoo0Wb7ijfnYJVzoqAynWwdfssbQpGmDbd8cjRzlmD9LStc9Y16tkvDcGUsIZ1ZDl7e/zlr0d4gmizHNRVGHelrfOom4GyDLIl7EALGMWARtizBbZyxCDo5VPult8wzXN2yPP8kLFf).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda